# Check if all items in python list contain substring

Tags: python

I have a python list, that I am getting from api:

```
ERRATA_PKG_LIST = []
packages_key = "packages"
for pkgs, package_name in errata_rhel_ver_dic.iteritems():
    if pkgs == packages_key:
       ERRATA_PKG_LIST.append(package_name)
print(ERRATA_PKG_LIST)
```

Output:

```
[u'kernel-2.6.18-416.el5.i686',
 u'kernel-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64',
 u'kernel-debug-2.6.18-416.el5.i686',
 u'kernel-debug-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64',
 u'kernel-debug-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.i686',
 u'kernel-debug-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64',
 u'kernel-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.i686',
 u'kernel-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64',
 u'kernel-doc-2.6.18-416.el5.noarch',
 u'kernel-headers-2.6.18-416.el5.i386',
 u'kernel-headers-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64',
 u'kernel-PAE-2.6.18-416.el5.i686',
 u'kernel-PAE-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.i686',
 u'kernel-xen-2.6.18-416.el5.i686',
 u'kernel-xen-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64',
 u'kernel-xen-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.i686',
 u'kernel-xen-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64']
```

I want to check that each and every item in the list contains the substring: el5
if all of the objects in the list contains el5 ,then assign a variable 
rhel = "rhel 5" ,how do I achieve that ?

Comment: try python built-in function `all`

Comment: If `errata_rhel_ver_dic` is a dictionary then there should be unique values of `pkgs`, and only one of them `== packages_key`

Answer (score 10):

To test if every item matches a certain condition, try the builtin function [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) along with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). In the generator expression, the test for substring containment is the [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).

To filter a list, selecting only items which match some condition, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

To print a list,the [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method is often useful.

```
ERRATA_PKG_LIST = [u'kernel-2.6.18-416.el5.i686', u'kernel-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64', u'kernel-debug-2.6.18-416.el5.i686', u'kernel-debug-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64', u'kernel-debug-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.i686', u'kernel-debug-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64', u'kernel-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.i686', u'kernel-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64', u'kernel-doc-2.6.18-416.el5.noarch', u'kernel-headers-2.6.18-416.el5.i386', u'kernel-headers-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64', u'kernel-PAE-2.6.18-416.el5.i686', u'kernel-PAE-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.i686', u'kernel-xen-2.6.18-416.el5.i686', u'kernel-xen-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64', u'kernel-xen-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.i686', u'kernel-xen-devel-2.6.18-416.el5.x86_64']


# To determine if 'el5' appears in every item
if all('el5' in item for item in ERRATA_PKG_LIST):
    rhel = "rhel 5"

# To generate the list of items which contain 'el5'
el5_list = [item for item in ERRATA_PKG_LIST if 'el5' in item]

# To generate the list of items which do NOT contain 'el5'
not_el5_list = [item for item in ERRATA_PKG_LIST if 'el5' not in item]

# To print a list:
print('\n'.join(el5_list))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, how to print list item/items, that not contains `el5`? [**For example**](https://www.pastery.net/xsgnud/). Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных - use a list comprehension. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
if all(['el5' in item for item in ERRATA_PKG_LIST]):
    rhel = "rhel 5"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if all(map(lambda pkg: "el5" in pkg, ERRATA_PKG_LIST)):
        rhel = "rhel 5"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `in`.

```
def CheckList(list_items):
    for item in list_items:
        if 'el5' not in item:
            return False
    return True
```

This way you are going to loop through all elements of the list and check if the substring 'el5' is not in that item, if that evaluates true, your function returns False. Otherwise, it will end the loop and return True.

Comment: This is the same as `not any('el5' not in ...`, which is the same as `all('el5' in ...`

Comment: Yes I know that, just started answering before those answers and finished later, didn't feel the need of erasing my answer just because it's similar/same of previous ones